# React dispatch a method in async call

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, middleware

How to dispatch the redux function in react async call. When I call the dispatch function `dispatch(updatingcontact()`, I'm getting error that dispatch is not defined.

```
const UpdateContact = async (URL, method, type, address) => {
dispatch(updatingcontact()
const APIResponse = await fetch(URL, {
    method: POST,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "webContacts": {
            "address": address
        }
    })
})
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(status => {
        return status
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I just want to call the `updatingcontact()` function inside the `UpdateContact` and call the reducer to display the updating message in UI.

```
function updatingcontact() {
return {
    type: ACTIONTYPES.UPDATING_CONTACT
 }
}
```

Comment: You can use [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Comment: @HMR I'm getting this error `Syntax error: await is a reserved word` while using `return (dispatch) => {dispatch(updatingcontact())}`.

Comment: check this out this as an async middleware  [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-dispatch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use some async middleware like `redux-thunk` to make asynchronous API calls. Using redux's higher order function `connect` will connect your React component to the redux store.

Your thunk would look something like this:

**Note that Redux will pass `dispatch` argument to the thunk function for dispatching actions.**

```js
export const updatingContact = (url, address) => {
  return async (dispatch) => { 
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONTYPES.UPDATING_CONTACT_STARTS }) // for showing spinner or loading state in your component

    try {
      const response = axios.post(url, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        },

        body: JSON.stringify({
          webContacts: {
            address: address
          }
        })
      })

      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONTYPES.UPDATING_CONTACT_SUCCESS,
        data: { updatedContactList: response.data.updatedContactList }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: ACTIONTYPES.UPDATING_CONTACT_ERROR,
        data: { error: error }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

After that, whatever your component needs, it's availble in the redux store. To `dispatch` from your `UpdateContact` component, you just need to do this:

```js
import { updatingContact } from "./actions.js" 

class UpdateContact extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.dispatch(updatingContact()) 
  }

  render() { 
    const {address, phoneNumber } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        Adress: {address}
        Phone No.: {phoneNumber}
      </div>
    )
  }


const mapStateToProps = () => {
  // return whatever you need from the store like contact details, address, etc
  address: state.updatingContactReducer.address,
  phoneNumber: state.updatingContactReducer.phoneNumber
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UpdateContact)
```

**Notice that if you don't provide `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect`, you will still be able to use `dispatch` in your component because it's available by default.**

If you provide `mapDispatchToProps`, the way you would now dispatch from your component would be- `this.props.updatingContact()`.

`mapDispatchToProps` just binds action creators with dispatch and pass these new bound functions as props to the component.

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned by HMR, you should use [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) to have async calls in redux actions.

The easiest is to have a look at [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) that is installing all standard redux middlewares for you (including redux-thunk)